# Will my AMD fx8320e 8-core run windows 10 64bit?

Tags: windows-10, cpu, 64-bit

Ive been looking online and could find an answer with regard to my actual CPU.

I was just wondering it i could run a 64 bit version with my setup at the moment i have put in the specs below it does say its an x64 based processor but apparently from my googling it says there could be other problems

I only really want to run 64bit as i have heard it is fast than 32bit when you have more than 4gb RAM and when using 32bit you can only ever use 4gb anyway and i have more installed.

32Gb SSD (for operating system) 500Gb 2nd hard drive
8GB Ram 
AMD FX-8320E 8 core 3.20ghz (Vishera)
x64-based processor
(supports Instructions MMX+,SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSE4.1,SSE4.2,SSE4A,X84-64,AMD-V,AES,AVX,XOP,FMA3FMA4.)

Comment: The processor is a x86-64 processor.  All x86-64 processors support 64-bit operating systems.  If you want to be more specific, that requires you telling us, what these "problems" are exactly.

Comment: I guess problems was wrong, i thought i would check as this website said you needed EM64T,VT-x,SSE2 to run it. http://www.howtogeek.com/228042/how-to-switch-from-32-bit-windows-10-to-64-bit-windows-10/

Comment: Edit your question to include which problems your talking about, VT-x isn't required, for any version of Windows.

Comment: VT-X is intel only and for virtualization - If you don't run stuff like virtualbox in certain configurations you wouldn't need it at all. AMD-V is the AMD equivalent of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the information I needed to answer your question was included *in* your question. But I also have a third-party source definitely confirming this.

Third-party source: http://www.anandtech.com/show/8864/amd-fx-8320e-cpu-review-the-other-95w-vishera (it's in the details)

First-party source (your question):

> X86-64

All a CPU requires, strictly speaking, to run Windows 10 64-bit is support for the "AMD64" microarchitecture (variously referred to as X86_64, x86-64, x86 64-bit, etc. etc. etc.) Note that no CPU manufactured by AMD will ever support "EM64T", but EM64T is just Intel's specific implementation of the AMD64 architecture. It's mostly compatible with AMD's own implementation, enough that Windows 64-bit will work just fine on either one.

Only a few very low-end Intel processors manufactured for small tablets and smartphones are still being manufactured in recent years *without* 64-bit architecture support. All other Intel x86-based processors are shipping with 64-bit instruction set, including those from AMD. This means in practice that if you have a full-fat laptop or a desktop from, oh, the past decade or so, there is very little doubt that you'll be fine running a 64-bit OS.

The less-certain question is whether your system components, like RAM, disk, and graphics chipset, are good enough to run a new version of Windows. But in your case you should be fine there, too.

But, yeah. Whenever you upgrade to a new operating system *at all* -- regardless of whether you're migrating from 32-bit to 64-bit, or to a new version, or from, say, Windows to GNU/Linux -- you still need to consider, *component-by-component*, whether they meet minimum performance specifications required by that operating system, as well as having the appropriate drivers available. The CPU is not the only component to consider for compatibility, though it is definitely an important one!

Comment: Ok thank you for all your answers, i thought i would check as this website said you needed EM64T,VT-x,SSE2 to run it. http://www.howtogeek.com/228042/how-to-switch-from-32-bit-windows-10-to-64-bit-windows-10/

but like i said thank you for your quick anwser that is great

Comment: Also while im here 64bit or 32 bit, is there much speed difference i primarily wanted 64 bit too run a few games which arent available on32 bit and to use all my ram for a speed increase.

Comment: If you have 8 or 16 GB of RAM (or more...!), you will experience a significant speed-up in multi-tasking from switching to 64-bit Windows, because you'll have more RAM available for caching I/O reads. 32-bit games won't run any faster, but being able to run 64-bit games in the first place is definitely a bonus...

Comment: I'd note, in my experience, almost any desktop or mainstream laptop system made within the last 5 years would likely be able to support 64 bit. Any system which supports more than 4gb of ram would almost certainly support 64 bit. And when in doubt, you can always download a free linux livecd (64 bit of course!) to test for 64 bit support.

Comment: I'd note, in my experience, almost any desktop or mainstream laptop system made within the last 5 years would likely be able to support 64 bit. Any system which supports more than 4gb of ram would almost certainly support 64 bit. And when in doubt, you can always download a free linux livecd (64 bit of course!) to test for 64 bit support.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can definitely handle the 64 bit version, on windows 10,8,7,XP.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/570464)

Comment: The answer has a boolean return.  To say it doesn't provide an answer is incorrect.  It may not be an explained answer but it does indeed answer the question.